# In an XML document, is it possible to tell the difference between an entity-encoded character and one that is not?

Tags: java, xml, encoding, dom4j

I am being feed an XML document with metadata about online resources that I need to parse.  Among the different metadata items are a collection of tags, which are comma-delimited.  Here is an example:

```
<tags>Research skills, Searching&#44; evaluating and referencing</tags>
```

The issue is that one of these "tags" contains a comma in it.  The comma within the tag is encoded, but the commas intended to delimit tags are not.  I am (currently) using the [getText() method on org.dom4j.Node](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/org/dom4j/Node.html#getText()) to read the text content of the `<tags>` element, which returns a String.

The problem is that I am not able -- as far as I'm aware -- to differentiate the encoded comma (from the ones that aren't encoded) in the String I receive.

Short of writing my own XML parser, is there another way to access the text content of this node in a more "raw" state?  (viz. a state where the encoded comma is *still* encoded.)

Comment: The problem also occurs in the context of XSLT processing, there you can use Andrew Welch's `LexEv` (http://andrewjwelch.com/lexev/) to be plugged in instead of a normal `XMLReader`, it converts lexical events, including character references, into markup respectively nodes (e.g. the character reference `&#160;` is reported as  `<lexev:entity name="#160"> </lexev:entity>`). You might want to try whether it can be used together with your DOM API.

Comment: @Martin, are you sure LexEv will report character references? I didn't think this information was available at the SAX level. I know it reports parsed entity references, but that's a different matter.

Comment: When I wrote my comment I relied on the documentation, but I have now tried to run Saxon 9 together with LexEx and an identity transformation on the sample above in the question and it outputs the root element as `<tags xmlns:lexev="http://andrewjwelch.com/lexev">Research skills, Searching<lexev:char-ref name="#44">,</lexev:char-ref> evaluating and referencing</tags>`, so yes, it is able to identify character references, even if the normal SAX events don't cover them. I also needed to put `xercesImpl.jar` on the class path.

Answer (score 1):

When you use dom4j or DOM all the entities are already resolved, so you would need to go back to the parsing step to catch character references.

SAX is a more lowlevel interface and has support via its LexicalHandler interface to get notified when the parser encounters entity references, but it does not report character references. So it seems that you would really need to write an own parser, or patch an existing one.

But in the end it would be best if you can change the schema of your document:

```
<tags>
    <tag>Research skills</tag>
    <tag>Searching, evaluating and referencing</tag>
</tags>
```

In your current document character references are used to act as metadata. XML elements are a better way to express that.

Comment: I agree -- the representation of this info in the document needs to change.  As so often happens, I've been asking for this change for some time... and so far it hasn't come to be.

Comment: A lot of mistakes are made in designing XML representations of information, but I have to say it's the first time I have seen someone try to use the difference between a literal character and its hex code as a semantically-significant distinction.

Answer (score 1):

Using `LexEv` from http://andrewjwelch.com/lexev/, putting `xercesImpl.jar` from Apache Xerces on the class path, I am able to compile and run some short sample using `dom4j`:

```
    LexEv lexEv = new LexEv();

    SAXReader reader = new SAXReader(lexEv);

    Document doc = reader.read("input1.xml");

    System.out.println(doc.getRootElement().asXML());
```

If the input1.xml has your sample XML snippet, then the output is

```
<tags xmlns:lexev="http://andrewjwelch.com/lexev">Research skills, Searching<lexev:char-ref name="#44">,</lexev:char-ref> evaluating and referencing</tags>
```

So that way you could get a representation of your input where a pure character and a character reference can be distinguished.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, every XML processing frameworks (except [vtd-xml](http://vtd-xml.sf.net)) resolve entities during parsing....

you can only distinguish a character from its entity encoded counterpart using vtd-xml by using VTDNav's toRawString() method...